# Double clicking on headers of NSOutlineView is triggering double-click method?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've a set a double-click action for my NSOutlineView, everything is working well:every time I double click on a row in the table, the correct method is invoked.

However, the same method is invoked when I double click on the header of a column (let's say to change the sort order). I've never noticed this behaviour before, how could I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about checking the clickedRow?

```
[self.outlineView clickedRow]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that's very easy fix. I opened the bounty because I found it very strange that a header could trigger the action.